# PyMySQL using created output-file after connection is closed

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pymysql

I create a CSV file from an PyMySQL-request (works). Then the CSV-content is read in with pandas and processed in python (works). Then the CSV-file should be deleted (**does not work**), the error message being

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/testing.csv'

```
 import pymysql
 import os

 path = 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/testing.csv'
 db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","****","testdb")
 cursor = db.cursor()
 sql = "SELECT * FROM t_names INTO OUTFILE '" + path + "' " \
       "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
 cursor.execute(sql)

 db.close()

 #Some python operations with the read-in file are here

 os.remove(path)
```

During the process I create (with pandas) and delete (with os) multiple other CSV-files in the same folder as "testing.csv". This is working.
I suspect that something in PyMySQL is still using the file it created even though the SQL-connection is closed. Any advice?

Comment: What are the operations you are doing that are commented out?

Comment: I import from other (existing) CSV-files and compare certain fields. Depending on this, a new CSV-file is written. I have found a workaround. If I modify the sql-request without the INTO OUTFILE part and export it via pandas to a CSV-file, then I can delete the file as well..